# printing a line number for each line entered in standard input

Tags: c, numbers, line, stdout, stdin

what i want to do is print a number for each line entered. eg when a user enters "jaguar", the program will output:

1 jaguar

and if the user then enters "lion" the output should be:

2 lion.

In other words the screen will be looking like this:

jaguar
1 jaguar
lion
2 lion
leopard
3 leopard...

Sounds easy yes. Here is my code which is printing things wrongly and i dont understand how and why....

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  int lineNum = 0;
  char c;
  while(  (c= fgetc(stdin) )  != EOF)          
  {
    if(c == '\n')
    {
      lineNum++;
      printf("\n %i", lineNum);
    }
    else
    {
      fputc(c, stdout);
    }
  }
  //return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you ?

```
char buffer[256];
int i = 1;

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)) {
    printf("%d %s", i, buffer);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: hahaha you are a genius cnicutar,, THANK YOU VERY MUCH.. this got me puzzled for a 2 days...

Comment: @cnicutar : well, this is just usefull to a particalr extent. Is there a way to do the same thing, for example using the approach i had tried before and not an approach that does not allow me to do more than just printing line numbers. Thanks

Comment: @user870565 What do you want to do "more" ?

Comment: @cnicutar: okay let me be straight, if i write: fputs("hello",stdout);  then below that i write: fputc(51,stdout)  the result will be like this: hello3... its a 3 since 51 is 3(not to say you dont know). Is there a way to insert the 3 in front of the hello o make it look like this 3hello, without changing the order.. changing the order would ofcoz solve the problem but thats not wat i want.

Comment: hey I managed to fix the problem that I had, its the way I had tried to implement my program from the beginning..

Comment: @cnicutar : could you explain how the sollution you gave works exactly. I have an idea yes but jus need to know how it works from you. Thank you in advance

Comment: @user870565 `fgets` reads an entire string (until newline or 255 chars) and printf prints it and a number before it. Fiddling with ASCII and `fputc` and `fgetc` is not the right direction